# ssh from linux to windows does nothing

Tags: linux, ssh, windows

I installed KpyM on my Windows 10 machine and started it. It says the service is running.

```
  Proto  Lokale Adresse         Remoteadresse          Status
  TCP    0.0.0.0:22             DESKTOP-4VRVV1O:0      ABHÖREN
```

So now I switch to my linux machine and do:
(username is the name I see when I login into windows 10?)

```
ssh <username>@<ip-windows>
```

After a while:

`ssh: connect to host <ip-windows> port 22: Connection timed out`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you open the port in Windows Firewall?

Comment: did SSH ever gain any traction in Windows 10 ?

Comment: @NasirRiley pls make an answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the issue is Windows firewall configuration.

Comment: ye u right gonna remove it later

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about Linux or Unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to open the port in Windows Firewall and restart the service before connecting. In your case, that's port 22.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below commands:

1. Login to the server using ssh
2. nc -v host port name
3. if the connection opened already, it should give the success message.
4. otherwise please open windows firewall connection